# SweetAlert: Unexpected 2nd argument

Tags: javascript, promesas, sweetalert, sweetalert2

Buenas tardes, tengo el siguiente código:

```
function desactivar(idcategoria)
{
swal({
 title: "Desactivar Categoría",
 text: "¿Está Seguro de desactivar la Categoría?",
 type: "warning",
 showCancelButton: true,
 confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
 confirmButtonText: "Si,desactivar!",
 closeOnConfirm: false
},
function(result){
if (result) {
$.post("../ajax/categoria.php?op=desactivar",{idcategoria : idcategoria},function(e){
swal("Desactivado!",e, "success");
tabla.ajax.reload();
});
}

});

}
```

Pero al momento de presionar el boton que ejecuta la funcion aparece esto:

> Uncaught SweetAlert: Unexpected 2nd argument

No se exactamente como solucionarlo, podrian darme una ayuda por favor?

Gracias!

Comment: Hola Betto, te doy  la bienvenida!, te invito a seguir el [tour] para entender el funcionamiento básico del sitio, puedes leer [ask] que te brinda información para realizar una buena pregunta y obtener excelentes respuestas, saludos y bienvenido.

Comment: Betto que versión de SweetAlert usas???

Comment: Hola Jorge, estoy utilizando la versión 2.0.4 actualmente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El código que describes en tu respuesta es de una versión anterior a 2, actualmente debes usar [promises](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#using-promises), revisa la [guia](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#upgrading-from-1x).

```
swal("Click on either the button or outside the modal.")
.then((value) => {
  swal(`The returned value is: ${value}`);
});
```

De hecho otro detalle es que `closeOnConfirm` ya no es usado, debes usar `closeModal`.

```
swal({
 title: "Desactivar Categoría",
 text: "¿Está Seguro de desactivar la Categoría?",
 type: "warning",
 showCancelButton: true,
 confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
 confirmButtonText: "Si,desactivar!",
 closeModal: false

   }).then(
  ...
  ...
});
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias Jorge!, funciono perfecto con tus recomendaciones! Saludos.

Comment: Un placer Betto, no olvides leer los documentos que te sugiero, saludos!